# node.js express throw exception variable

Tags: node.js, exception, express

I'd like to create a function wich have a var in argument, if the var is defined return the var value else return the var name

I try

```
test = function(variable){
    try{
        if ( typeof(variable) != "undefined" ) {
            return 'true'
        }
        return 'false'
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

}
```

but if I have an undefined var the function isn't called and I have the undefined function error.

I would like to know how to have the variable name too

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use `var` as your parameter. It it a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in JavaScript and doesn't describe what the variable is used for.

how about:

```
var test = function(variable) {
  if (!variable) return false;
  return variable;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, I change var in my post, Do you know how to return the variable name instead of false ?

Comment: what do you mean with 'variable name'? if there is no `variable` you cannot return the name. Or do you just want `return 'variable'`?

Comment: test(definedVar)=> definedVar: value  .

test(undefinedVar)=> undefinedVar  .

But from my searchs and as you say I can't get a variable name.